# laravel deployment failed on heroku

Tags: laravel, heroku

Some months ago I succeeded in deploying a Laravel 5.5 application on Heroku.

I tried to do the same today with a Laravel 6.12 application, and I have a lot of problems. I added the `.env` vars, I added the `Procfile`. But I have this error:

[image]

Did something change between Laravel 5.5 and 6 for deploying to Heroku? How can I get this working?

My `post-install-cmd` is:

```
"post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan cache:clear",
            "php artisan config:cache",
            "chmod -R 777 storage",
            "php artisan passport:keys"
        ]
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using the default `file` session driver, but this isn't a good fit on Heroku. [Its filesystem is ephemeral and local to each dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem).

[Try using a different session driver](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/session) by setting the `SESSION_DRIVER` environment variable:

```
heroku config:set SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
```

`cookie` is probably simplest, but `memcached` or `redis` would work well too if you have either of those set up.

The default session driver didn't change between Laravel 5.5 and 6, but I wouldn't recommend using `file` with Laravel 5.5 on Heroku either.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks a lot for your answer. I think I found the error . I installed a new fresh laravel project on heroku and it works fine on the first try ! I saw I had a "post-install-cmd" in my composer.json that I have not on a fresh project. I removed that and now it works ! I do not why I had that , and do not know the use of that. But the main is that is works fine now. Merci encore pour ton aide . Dom